# how to force an only downloadable pdf in your browser to be viewable in the browser

Tags: php, pdf, embed, lightbox

I have been trying to display a data access policy(URL PDF file) in my tool and initially tried implementing it using the lighbox feature. It did not work for my PDF URL file but it did work for some other test PDF URL file.

I think the problem here is that the PDF is in ONLY DOWNLOADABLE FORMAT in a browser and NOT VIEWABLE in the browser.

I also tried to embed the source PDF URL file but it just returns a plain grey box and nothing else.

Can someone please tell me how can I force this PDF to be viewable in the browser so the user can see the agreement without downloading it?

Thanks.

/rd

Answer (score 0):

content-disposition:inline is probably what you want.

Inline read into the browser
Attachment make it for download.

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please tell me how can I force this PDF to be viewable in the browser so the user can see the agreement without downloading it?

If the user doesn't have a PDF reader installed or have his or her browser's MIME types set so that PDFs are open within it with a reader, there's no way you can control that. Also, even though it opens in a browser, the client can still save it locally, so the data is *downloaded* anyway.

Comment: @rdodev-I would just like to make it viewable using an embed tag. Isnt that possible?

Comment: @rond I understand what you are trying to do. What I'm saying is that that's not supported by all browsers and OS. For instance, some browsers will automatically download it when they see a content-type application/pdf unless they are configured to open a viewer inside itself, like Chrome does, for example. Your best bet for agreements is a div with agreement text in it on a greybox or modal window.

Comment: @rdodev-understood. Here's the problem the agreement is 11 pages long :(

Comment: @rond holy jeebus. In that case, if it's THAT important for people to read through it, I would strongly suggest static whole HTML pages with back and forth navigation and then have them electronically sign the terms at the end.